# Maximum scale dependent visibility changes from 1:0 to -2147483648:1

Tags: qgis, scale

QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour.
When i open the layer properties and the scale dependent visibility is unchecked and when i check it, the maximum (inclusive) shows 1:0. I click Apply, OK, reopen layer properties and it says -2147483648:1.
Everytime i change it to 1:0, apply and reopen the layer properties, the maximum (inclusive) gives me the value -2147483648:1.
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem: the issue I encountered was when I was following the instructions in the QGIS training manual Lesson 2.5 (Symbology). Carefully following (or so I thought) the instructions and screen grabs provided in the manual, I set the values for my chosen layer in the 'Minimum' box to 1:0 and the 'Maximum' box to 1:10,000. I could not understand how, no matter which scale I subsequently chose, the layer simply would not appear; moreover, when I re-opened the Layer properties, I found the value in the 'Maximum' box kept reverting to the value you describe: -2,147,483,648:1.

But then a closer look revealed that the image in the training manual shows the layer properties box with the 'Minimum' box on the RIGHT-hand side, and the 'Maximum' box on the LEFT-hand side; a reversal of how it is on the current QGIS version (which shows 'Minimum' on the LEFT and 'Maximum' on the RIGHT). In my haste to complete the section I had not noticed that the boxes in the instructions and the program were swapped around; and having assumed they would be the same way around, I blithely entered the values in the wrong boxes: no wonder I couldn't get it to work. Changing the values to 1:10,000 in the LEFT-hand ('Minimum') box; and 1:1 in the RIGHT-hand ('Maximum') box solved the problem: my layers are now fully 'scale dependent'.

That said, I remain unconvinced that the wording of the boxes is correct: I believe that the maximum scale should show the maximum scale value before the layer ceases to be visible, and ditto for the mimimum scale - in other words, 1:1 should be in the minimum box and 1:10,000 in the maximum box. I could be wrong, of course, but maybe this is a long-standing quirk of QGIS that I haven't picked up before.

Answer (score 0):

re the minimum and maximum, scale is a ratio, so 1:1 is larger than 1:10000.
1:1 is a large scale, and 1:10000 is a small scale.  I think the minimum and maximum is formally correct.